# как отправлять формы без перезагрузки

Tags: php, javascript

Подскажите как сделать что бы после отправки просто на той же странице вместо формы показать модальное окно об успешном отправлении, сейчас после отправки я вижу пустую страницу

Comment: ajax вам нужен.

Answer (score 0):

Тут все зависит от того что вы хотите послать, и как будете обрабатывать ответ, самый простой вариант будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
<form id="form">
 <!-- inputs -->
</form>

<script>
    var form = document.getElementById('form');

    form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        var body = new FormData(form);

        fetch('https://api.exemple.com', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: body
        }).then((response) => {
            // Удачный запрос
        }).catch((error) => {
            // Завершился ошибкой
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: а url обработчика мне вставить вместо https://api.exemple.com?

Comment: @dmitro_bolva  адрес куда вы хотите отправить форму, я же не знаю куда )